# Observable TcpListener terminates after single connection

Tags: c#, sockets, system.reactive

I'm new to Rx, so I'm probably making some essential mistakes here.

I wanted to create a very simple socket server that could receiver messages from clients using Observables. For this I'm using Rxx, which provides extension methods in the System.Net.Sockets namespace, and also provides the ObserableTcpListener static factory class.

Here's what I have so far, pretty much stole it from various sources:

```
IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9001);
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(endpoint);

IObservable<TcpClient> clients = listener
    .StartSocketObservable(1)
    .SelectMany<Socket, TcpClient>(socket => SocketToTcpClient(socket));
    .Finally(listener.Stop)

clients.Subscribe(client =>
{
    OnConnect(client).Subscribe(
        message => OnMessage(client, message),
        ex => OnException(client, ex),
        () => OnCompleted(client));
});

private static IObservable<TcpClient> SocketToTcpClient(Socket socket)
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    client.Client = socket;
    return Observable.Return<TcpClient>(client);
}

private static IObservable<byte[]> OnConnect(TcpClient client)
{
    return client.Client.ReceiveUntilCompleted(SocketFlags.None);
}

private static void OnMessage(TcpClient client, byte[] message)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Mesage Received! - {0}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message));
}

private static void OnCompleted(TcpClient client)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Completed.");
}

private static void OnException(TcpClient client, Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.ToString());
}
```

This works... up to a point. I can make a single Client connection. As soon as that connection terminates, it would seem the Observable sequence terminates and `.Finally(listener.Stop)` is called. Obviously, that's not what I want.

I tried using the `ObserableTcpListener.Start()` factory class, but that nets me the exact same result.

```
IObservable<TcpClient> sockets = ObservableTcpListener.Start(endpoint);
sockets.Subscribe(client =>
{
    OnConnect(client).Subscribe(
        message => OnMessage(client, message),
        ex => OnException(client, ex),
        () => OnCompleted(client));
});
```

I suppose I do understand the problem here: the `clients` observable sequence is simply empty after the first client terminates, thus `.Finally(listener.Stop)` is called.

What would I need to do to circumvent this? How can I keep listening for incoming connections?

Comment: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/14317362/ to me the code looks like it only accept one connection. Anyway, would advise to drop this approach and use standard techniques for running sockets. I cannot see any advantage that this has over using TcpListener/Client directly, possibly with await.

Comment: @usr The main reasons are that, for the most part, I do enjoy writing code the Rx-way because it's both very readable and expresses one's intent very clearly. Second reason is that I was writing a bunch of different event-style code, and Rx provides a nice abstraction over all those styles with the ability to keep the patterns the same. Third, I'm just trying to learn Rx. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: If I may add a counter argument to that: This style splits normal, sequential code into callbacks which is generally a terrible thing for code quality. For example, you have the classic bug in your code where you assume that TCP sends "messages". It does not, and therefore the `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` will sometimes return garbage if you get unlucky and your "message" is split midway through a UTF8 encoded code point. This is hard to fix in this style. In sequential code you could use StreamReader or BinaryReader and pull the data. With push you have to take what comes.

Comment: Looks like someone has their mind made up on how they want to write code. I would say that this is a great use case for Functional Reactive Programming and Rx. Keep it going  :-)

Comment: @usr I strongly appreciate your concerns. However, do keep in mind that is not actual application code. This is just me trying to get something up and running. I'm well aware of the fact that there are no "messages", just byte strings (containing whatever), and that carelessly trying to convert them to UTF8 strings is pretty dangerous. This was actually one of the problems I was interested in investigating (regardless of result). Furthermore, I think comparing the Rx reactive style to traditional callbacks is a little unfair. Either way, I'm keeping your comments in mind.

Comment: Just a small comment - The `On*` naming convention, i.e. `OnConnect`, is used for the method in the class that owns the event to raise the event and not the method name that handles the event.

Comment: @RobinMattheussen did you give a go at my solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your `Observable` *hot* and persist while there are subscriptions.

```
IObservable<TcpClient> clients = listener
    .StartSocketObservable(1)
    .SelectMany<Socket, TcpClient>(socket => SocketToTcpClient(socket))
    .Finally(listener.Stop)
    .Publish().RefCount();
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I fell ill for a while after posting this question, and I totally forget I asked it. Either way, I tried it a couple of hours ago, and yes, this actually does seem to have fixed it.